# Angular 5 Checkbox in *ngFor Loop and get check and unchecked particular checkbox

Tags: checkbox, angular5, ngfor

Any Idea in Angular 5 where I have the checkbox in *ngFor loop so I want to know how this is getting the change in check and uncheck for the particular checkbox in *ngFor.

I have some code as below

```html
<tr *ngFor="let addon of group?.item_addons; let i = index;">
   <td>
       <div class="form-check">
         <label class="form-check-label">
           <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
           (change)="onselectAddon(addon,$event,group,i)">
           <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
              {{addon.addons_name}}
         </label>
        <span class="float-right">+ {{addon.addons_price}}</span>
       </div>                                                                            
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get selected and unselected value from particular checkbox.

Comment: you forgot to add your code. Also it's not clear what are you asking.

Comment: Sorry, I added code have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add to your input the following:

```
[checked]="someExpression"
```

if you prefer, you could call a function where you pass the current addon like

```
[checked]="isChecked(addon)"
```